# Separating radioButtons in R shiny app with a line break

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I have a list of radioButtons on my shiny app that I am looking to separate into three groups, either with a Header, a blank space like a line or paragraph break, or even a line --------. 
I tried to do this by creating three separate formTypes of buttons (formType1, formType2, formType3) but the functionality of the buttons stopped working. I don't know much HTML code, but the ones I tried wouldn't work in the radioButton code chunk. Can you help? Thanks. I've indicated where I want the radioButtons separated below with `**BREAK HERE**`

```
# Create Navigation Bar
   navbarPage("Navigation Bar",
     # Create a tab for data Entry
     tabPanel(
       "Data Entry",
       sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
           radioButtons(
             "formType", "Form Type",
             c("Basic Info & Universal Flagging" = "basic_info",
               "Universal Screening" = "uni_screening",

               `**BREAK HERE**`

               "BHAP Screening" = "bhap_screening",
               "BHAP Intake & Assessment" = "bhap_intakeassessment",
               "BHAP Referral" = "bhap_referral", "BHAP Contact Info" = "bhap_contactinfo",
               "BHAP Case Management" = "bhap_casemanagement", "BHAP Exit" = "bhap_exit", 

               `**BREAK HERE**`

               "COAP Intake" = "coap_intake", "COAP Assessment" = "coap_assessment", 
               "Intercept 3: COAP In-Jail Servces" = "coap_injailservices",
               "Intercept 4: COAP Support Services Needs" = "coap_supportservices",
               "Intercept 4: COAP Reentry/Community-Based Referrals" = "coap_reentrycommunity",
               "Provider Updates (In-Jail and Community-Based)" = "coap_providerupdates",
               "COAP Contact Info" = "coap_contactinfo", "COAP Case Management" = "coap_casemanagement",
               "COAP EXIT" = "coap_exit"))
           ),

         # outputs the dynamic UI component
          uiOutput("ui")
         )
       ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add javascript/jQuery to specify breaks after specific radio buttons, adding `<hr>` when indicated:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Create Navigation Bar
  navbarPage("Navigation Bar",
    # Create a tab for data Entry
    tabPanel(
     "Data Entry",
     sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(
         radioButtons(
           "formType", "Form Type",
           c("Basic Info & Universal Flagging" = "basic_info",
             "Universal Screening" = "uni_screening",
             "BHAP Screening" = "bhap_screening",
             "BHAP Intake & Assessment" = "bhap_intakeassessment",
             "BHAP Referral" = "bhap_referral", "BHAP Contact Info" = "bhap_contactinfo",
             "BHAP Case Management" = "bhap_casemanagement", "BHAP Exit" = "bhap_exit", 
             "COAP Intake" = "coap_intake", "COAP Assessment" = "coap_assessment", 
             "Intercept 3: COAP In-Jail Servces" = "coap_injailservices",
             "Intercept 4: COAP Support Services Needs" = "coap_supportservices",
             "Intercept 4: COAP Reentry/Community-Based Referrals" = "coap_reentrycommunity",
             "Provider Updates (In-Jail and Community-Based)" = "coap_providerupdates",
             "COAP Contact Info" = "coap_contactinfo", "COAP Case Management" = "coap_casemanagement",
             "COAP EXIT" = "coap_exit")),
         tags$head(tags$script(HTML("
             $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $('input[value=\"uni_screening\"]').parent().parent().after('<hr>');
                $('input[value=\"bhap_exit\"]').parent().parent().after('<hr>');
             })
             ")))
       ),
       # outputs the dynamic UI component
       uiOutput("ui")
     )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting **hr()**, which is a *horizontal rule*.  This should put in a space with a horizontal line.  Another option would be **br()**, a *blank rule*, doing the same minus the line.